# WebSphere listener port to listen on multiple queues

Tags: websphere

In WebSphere, can a listener port listen on multiple queues at the same time? Something like the reconnect functionality of the connection factory where you specify a list of hosts, but that is more like an 'alternative' connection list. I would like 2 connections to work at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use message selectors.
[Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncer/index.html)
[IBM Docs](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.doc/jm25420_.htm)